# Getting 403 error when trying to retrieve an Azure blob on Web API request

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-storage

I am trying to have an authenticated (by JWT) GET request return an image stored in an Azure blob. When I run the project on my local machine and use postman to request an image and the request goes through and I do get the image I requested. However, once I deploy the code to Azure and hit the same endpoint I get a 403. The code fails at the line in which I try to invoke DownloadToStreamAsync. Here is the code I'm using:

```
public async Task<BlobDownloadModel> DownloadBlob(Guid blobId)
    {
        try
        {
            //get picture record
            Picture file = await _media.GetPictureAsync(blobId);

            await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("got picture record");

            // get string format blob name
            var blobName = file.PictureId.ToString() + file.Extension;

            await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("got name of blob " + blobName);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(blobName))
            {
                await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("blob not empty");

                var blob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

                await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("got blob: " + blob.ToString());

                var ms = new MemoryStream();

                await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms);

                await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("blob downloaded to memory stream");

                var lastPos = blob.Name.LastIndexOf('/');
                var fileName = blob.Name.Substring(lastPos + 1, blob.Name.Length - lastPos - 1);

                var download = new BlobDownloadModel
                {
                    BlobStream = ms,
                    BlobFileName = fileName,
                    BlobLength = blob.Properties.Length,
                    BlobContentType = blob.Properties.ContentType
                };

                return download;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("exception thrown: " + ex.ToString());
        }
```

I would greatly appreciate any help I can get.

**UPDATE:**

I changed my code to this and tried again:

```
public async Task<AzureBlobModel> DownloadBlob(Guid blobId)
    {
        try
        {
            //get picture record
            Picture file = await _media.GetPictureAsync(blobId);

            await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("got picture record");

            // get string format blob name
            var blobName = file.PictureId.ToString() + file.Extension;

            await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("got name of blob " + blobName);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(blobName))
            {
                await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("blob not empty");

                var blob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

                await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("got blob: " + blob.ToString());

                // Strip off any folder structure so the file name is just the file name
                var lastPos = blob.Name.LastIndexOf('/');
                var fileName = blob.Name.Substring(lastPos + 1, blob.Name.Length - lastPos - 1);

                await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("got fileName: " + fileName);

                //await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms);

                await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("about to open read stream");

                var stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync();

                await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("opened read stream");

                var result = new AzureBlobModel()
                {
                    FileName = fileName,
                    FileSize = blob.Properties.Length,
                    Stream = stream,
                    ContentType = blob.Properties.ContentType
                };

                await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("blob downloaded to memory stream");

                return result;

                // Build and return the download model with the blob stream and its relevant info
                //var download = new BlobDownloadModel
                //{
                //    BlobStream = ms,
                //    BlobFileName = fileName,
                //    BlobLength = blob.Properties.Length,
                //    BlobContentType = blob.Properties.ContentType
                //};

                //return download;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("exception thrown: " + ex.ToString());
        }

        await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("returning null");

        // Otherwise
        return null;
    }
```

the results from the log for the last try is this:

request received and authenticated, timestamp UTC: 3/10/2017 5:28:26 AM -   5:28:26 AM
id received: b3bc7faf-0c86-4ce2-af84-30636825a485   - 5:28:27 AM
got picture record  -5:28:27 AM
got name of blob b3bc7faf-0c86-4ce2-af84-30636825a485.JPG   - 5:28:27 AM
blob not empty  - 5:28:27 AM
got blob: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob    - 5:28:27 AM
got fileName: b3bc7faf-0c86-4ce2-af84-30636825a485.JPG  - 5:28:27 AM
about to open read stream   - 5:28:27 AM

I was able to retrieve the name of the file/blob which eliminates an incorrect account key as the culprit of the issue.

**SOLUTION**

I was able to get my code to work with the following code:

```
public async Task<AzureBlobModel> DownloadBlob(Guid blobId)
    {
        try
        {
            //get picture record
            Picture file = await _media.GetPictureAsync(blobId);

            // get string format blob name
            var blobName = file.PictureId.ToString() + file.Extension;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(blobName))
            {
                var blob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

                // Strip off any folder structure so the file name is just the file name
                var lastPos = blob.Name.LastIndexOf('/');
                var fileName = blob.Name.Substring(lastPos + 1, blob.Name.Length - lastPos - 1);

                var fileLength = blob.Properties.Length;
                var stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync();

                var result = new AzureBlobModel()
                {
                    FileName = fileName,
                    FileSize = blob.Properties.Length,
                    Stream = stream,
                    ContentType = blob.Properties.ContentType
                };

                return result;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("exception thrown: " + ex.ToString());
        }

        await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("returning null");

        // Otherwise
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using the following code:

```
public async Task<AzureBlobModel> DownloadBlob(Guid blobId)
    {
        try
        {
            //get picture record
            Picture file = await _media.GetPictureAsync(blobId);

            // get string format blob name
            var blobName = file.PictureId.ToString() + file.Extension;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(blobName))
            {
                var blob = _container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

                // Strip off any folder structure so the file name is just the file name
                var lastPos = blob.Name.LastIndexOf('/');
                var fileName = blob.Name.Substring(lastPos + 1, blob.Name.Length - lastPos - 1);

                var fileLength = blob.Properties.Length;
                var stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync();

                var result = new AzureBlobModel()
                {
                    FileName = fileName,
                    FileSize = blob.Properties.Length,
                    Stream = stream,
                    ContentType = blob.Properties.ContentType
                };

                return result;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("exception thrown: " + ex.ToString());
        }

        await _log.CreateLogEntryAsync("returning null");

        // Otherwise
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, once I deploy the code to Azure and hit the same endpoint I get a 403.

Firstly, please check your Azure account and key to ensure they are correct. Secondly, please check the clock on the server. The storage services ensure that a request is no older than 15 minutes by the time it reaches the service. if the time on your server is not sync with storage server, it will give your 403 error.

Comment: I double checked to make sure the account credentials are correct. Both the web server and the blob storage are on the US West coast. I'm assuming the server times are synced. Do you know how I could check the times?

Comment: Do you use storage emulator to test? If you deploy to Azure, please ensure you change it with the Azure storage connection. Please also check the account key to ensure it is not re-generated. It is easy to check the server time. Please try to get the time on the server to be sure the time is correct with your watch.

Comment: Jambor, I'm certain that the account key is correct I went ahead and tested by running the API on the local machine and I was able to retrieve the image from the live storage account. I went ahead and took this screenshot of the request data https://24hr.cloudtimecards.com/File/Download/29021dd3-d1b8-4426-ab61-f061a340d855 

Also, I was not able to check the time on the Azure storage server. I looked on the Azure Portal with no luck.