# Why is my base64 string only display part of my picture?

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, reactjs, azure-blob-storage

On a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800783/download-azure-blob-and-set-it-as-data-url-on-an-image-tag/42804065#42804065) I received help from the community to set the resulting base64 string as the src attribute, however, the image or images are missing the bottom part of the image. Please see image below.

[image: Resulting partial image]

Below is the code I'm using to set the image content. How can get the rest of the image to display?

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as settings from './settings';

export default class Post extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            profileImage:'img/loading.gif'
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        if(this.props.post.PostImageId != "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"){
            // get post image data
            _rvw.getImage(this.props.post.PostImageId)
            .then((res)=>{
                this.setState({
                    postImage: "data:" + res.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + res.data
                });
            });
        }
        else //no image
        {
            this.setState({
                postImage: "img/no-image.png"
            });
        }
    }
    getImage(id){
        let config = {
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Authorization':'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
            }
        };
        return axios.get(settings.baseUrl()+'/mediacontent/get/'+id,config);
    }
    render(){
        return (<div className="image">
                <img ref="postMedia" src={this.state.postImage} />
            </div>);
    }
}
```

Full component can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/chesco9/bzu7ff86/).

Comment: First check the data you receive is complete.

Comment: Irrelevant, but still: btw, `this.props.post.ProfileImageId != null` check is likely to be redundant.

Comment: I double checked the size and it is correct. The blob on azure is 289.9kb and I'm receiving 290kb from the http response.

Comment: Wait, the blob of binary data is 289k? Or it's 289kb of base64?

Answer (score 0):

> `<img ref="postMedia" src={this.state.postImage} />`

Based on your post, the value of src should be this.state.profileImage instead of this.state.postImage. Please also check whether the other part of your image is covered by other UI elements. You could use the DOM Explorer window which provided by your browser to check the html elements and style sheet which applied on these html elements.

Comment: Hello Amor, I went ahead and did some corrections. I tried to extract the code from the full component to show only what pertained to the problem I'm having, but now I went ahead and added a link to the code for the full component. I hope this adds a bit more context.

Comment: I suggest you print out the base64 string both from C# side and JS side. Check whether they are different.  Then you can create a simple html file with one image tag and set the src property using the base64 string. It will help you locate the error position.